Why does the while loop not work without the XPeekEvent call?
Title says it all.
The code works with the XPeekEvent right before the while XCheckTypedEvent but without that the conditional evaluates to false and I have no idea why that might be.
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define false 0
#define true 1


int main(void)
{
    Display* dpy;
    XWindowAttributes attr;

    // state of cursor at the start of move/resize
    XButtonEvent cur_start;

    // return failure status if we can't connect
    if (!(dpy = XOpenDisplay(0x0))) return 1;

    char* keys_to_grab[] = {"F1"};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(keys_to_grab) / sizeof(keys_to_grab[0]); i++)
    {
        XGrabKey(dpy, XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, XStringToKeysym(keys_to_grab[i])), Mod1Mask,
            DefaultRootWindow(dpy), True, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
    }

    XGrabButton(dpy, 1, Mod1Mask, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), True,
            ButtonPressMask|ButtonReleaseMask|PointerMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);

    XGrabButton(dpy, 3, Mod1Mask, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), True,
            ButtonPressMask|ButtonReleaseMask|PointerMotionMask, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, None, None);

    cur_start.subwindow = None;

    for(;;)
    {
        XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
        switch(ev.type)
        {
            case KeyPress:
                if (ev.xkey.subwindow != None)
                    XRaiseWindow(dpy, ev.xkey.subwindow);
                break;

            case ButtonPress:
                if (ev.xbutton.subwindow != None)
                    cur_start = ev.xbutton;
                break;
                
            case MotionNotify:
                if (cur_start.subwindow != None)
                {
                    XPeekEvent(dpy, &ev);
                    while(XCheckTypedEvent(dpy, MotionNotify, &ev))
                    {
                        int xdiff = ev.xbutton.x_root - cur_start.x_root;
                        int ydiff = ev.xbutton.y_root - cur_start.y_root;
                       XMoveWindow(dpy, cur_start.subwindow,
                                attr.x + (cur_start.button==1 ? xdiff : 0),
                                attr.y + (cur_start.button==1 ? ydiff : 0));
                    }
                }
                break;

            case ButtonRelease:
                cur_start.subwindow = None;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

This is how I run the code: xinit ./xinitrc -- /usr/bin/Xephyr :100 -ac -screen 500x500 -host-cursor
With this as the xinitrc:
xclock &
xeyes &
sleep 2 && xterm &

exec ./a.out

and by "works", I mean I can drag the windows around.

It is unclear why you need either XPeekEvent or XCheckTypedEvent. Why not just get all events from the main loop?

From the manual page for XPeekEvent.

If the queue is empty, XPeekEvent flushes the output buffer and blocks until an event is received. It then copies the event into the client-supplied XEvent structure without removing it from the event queue.

I would guess that the event hasn't been received yet, so XPeekEvent is blocking until an event is received, and XCheckTypedEvent is then getting that event and handling it.
Considering that XPeekEvent will also copy the event structure into &ev and return True, you may be able to use XPeekEvent as your while condition and get rid of the call to XCheckTypedEvent.

Thought I'd RTFM'd with XPeekEvent but completely missed the "blocks" part. That just might be it, thanks. As with your suggestion to replace XCheckTypedEvent with XPeekEvent, I assumed I'd have to pop off the latest XEvent rather than just copying it, since I am using it's existance as a condition for the while loop.
